# How to set two properties for a React component as optional depending on another property using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I would like to know if it is possible to set two properties as optional depending on another property in TypeScript, example:

If `message` is `undefined` I want `a` and `b` to be required,
If `message` is `not undefined` I want `a` and `b` to be optional.

How to enforce this condition?

```
type Props = Readonly<{
  message?: React.ReactNode
  a: React.ReactNode
  b: React.ReactNode
}>

const Component = ({ message, a, b}: Props) => <div >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a union type to achieve this effect:

```
type Props = Readonly<{
    message?: undefined
    a: string
    b: string
} | {
    message: string
    a?: string
    b?: string
}>

const Component = ({ message, a, b}: Props) => <div />;

let c = <Component message="" /> //ok 
let c2 = <Component a="" b="" /> //ok
let c3 = <Component message="" b="" /> //ok 
let c4 = <Component /> //error as expected
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, do you know if conditional types from ts 2.8 can be of any help on this instance?

Comment: @GibboK don't really see how... conditional types help us make decisions based on another type. Here there is no need for a decision, both versions are valid.